# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: failing-tests

When we are running the test class getting below error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, You can't assign or unassign this
>   permission set because it's associated with a profile.: []

Please help me to below Test class:

```
@istest
public class UserReferenceRelatedRecordsTest{
public static testMethod void testInsert(){
        Id prId = [select Id from Profile where name = 'System Administrator' limit 1].Id;
        User u1 = TestFactory.getUser();
        u1.profileId = prId;
        u1.EmployeeNumber = '1234567';
        insert u1;
        System.debug(u1);
        System.debug('***'+[Select FederationIdentifier from User where id = :u1.Id]);
        Id psId = [select PermissionSetId from PermissionSetAssignment limit 1].PermissionSetId;
        System.debug('psId'+psId);  
        PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment();
        psa.AssigneeId = u1.Id;
        psa.PermissionSetId = psId;
        insert psa;
        Id plid = [SELECT PackageLicenseId FROM UserPackageLicense limit 1].PackageLicenseId;
        System.debug('plId'+plId);  
        UserPackageLicense upl = new UserPackageLicense();
        upl.PackageLicenseId = plid;
        upl.UserId = u1.Id;
        insert upl;
        Id gid = [SELECT GroupId FROM GroupMember where Group.Type = 'Regular' limit 1].GroupId;
        GroupMember gm = new GroupMember();
        gm.GroupId = gid;
        gm.UserOrGroupId = u1.Id;
        insert gm;


        User user1 = new User();
        user1.profileId = prId;
        user1.Username = 'TestUser_PS@testing.com';
        user1.Alias = 'tUser';
        user1.Email = 'TestUser_PS@testing.com';
        user1.EmailEncodingKey ='UTF-8';
        user1.LastName ='Testing';
        user1.LanguageLocaleKey ='en_US'; 
        user1.LocaleSidKey ='en_US';
        user1.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
        user1.FederationIdentifier='123123';
        user1.DOA_Area__c = 'NA';
        user1.Reference_SSO__c = '1234567';
        insert user1;    

        test.startTest();
        user1.isActive=false;
        update user1;
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that the code below is trying to take all of the user permissions from the Admin profile and create a permission set from them which is what the error message is telling you:

```
    Id psId = [select PermissionSetId from PermissionSetAssignment limit 1].PermissionSetId;
    System.debug('psId'+psId);  
    PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment();
    psa.AssigneeId = u1.Id;
    psa.PermissionSetId = psId;
    insert psa;
```

If not, it's totally unclear what permisionSet (and criteria) you're attempting to query. In any case, you can't insert a permission set that already exists.